# Can't create a file if a folder exists with the same name

Tags: file, directory, mkdir

The following code shows the problem I am experiencing:

```
// Assume working directory is empty.

File foo = new File("asdf");
foo.createNewFile(); // returns true, creates file "asdf" in working directory.

File bar = new File("asdf");
bar.mkdir(); // returns false
```

When I try to make a directory with the same name as a file that already exists, the "mkdir()" function returns false.
A similar problem occurs when the operations are performed in the opposite order; when the directory is made first, the "createNewFile()" function returns false.

I understand that when the second "File" object is initialised it 'finds' the file created on the previous line therefore "bar.exists() && bar.isFile()" is true.

Please could someone detail how I can create a file with the same name as an existing folder and vice-versa.

Thanks,
Harri

Comment: You should probably use the same variable name in your example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's impossible, since your operating system (file system) does not permit it. Not a Java issue as such.

Comment: Thank you, I'd assumed that this could be an issue without actually trying it in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a file and a folder with the same name and in the same folder. The OS would not allow you to do that since the name is the id for that file/folder object.

Assume it was possible and we'd have something like this:

```
foo (folder)
|- bar (folder)
|- bar (file)
```

How would you decide which one to open when you get a command "open foo/bar"?
If you can't decide with just that information, then how should the OS decide for you?

Answer (score 2):

It will not be possible as it's your operating system that doesn't allow it. You can always try and if it fails rename the folder (or file):

```
File bar = new File("asdf");
if(!bar.mkdir()) {
    // rename your folder or file
    bar.mkdir();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Assume working directory is empty.

File foo = new File("asdf.txt");
foo.createNewFile(); // returns true, creates file "asdf" in working directory.

File bar = new File("asdf");
bar.mkdir(); // returns false
```

The above code should work for you. Whenever you create file, give some extension so file and directory can be differentiated.